# Stream create two objects from one on some condition

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects.

Each object looks like `("1", "test","test1","25")`, I want to create two object from above example object filtering if my value test is present then create `("1", "test","25")` and if "test1" present then create new object  `("1", "test1","25")`

So if my object in list is `("1", "test","test1","25")`,
I will be creating two objects `("1", "test","25")` and `("1", "test1","25")`

If my object in list is `("1", "test","","25")`,
I will be creating only one objects `("1", "test","25")`

Comment: very unclear what you are asking

Comment: updated my query hope its clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your description is very abstract, I can tell you the solution only at the same abstract level.

You are looking for the [`flatMap` operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-). You can use it like

```
stream.flatMap(item -> condition(item)?
    Stream.of(createItemA(item), createItemB(item)): // two elements
    Stream.of(createItemA(item))                     // single elment
// chain subsequent operations
```